# Scrapy getting wrong values from request url

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract title from [This.](http://www.burbank.com.au) But getting different title which is not the resposnse url's title.
I am trying this-

```
class ElementSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'qwerty4'
    allowed_domains = ["burbank.com.au"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.burbank.com.au/victoria/home-details/alphington-153-179727", "https://www.burbank.com.au/victoria/home-details/sandringham-151-171569", "https://www.burbank.com.au/victoria/home-details/sandringham-151-181680", "https://www.burbank.com.au/victoria/home-details/bellfield-184-171585", "https://www.burbank.com.au/victoria/home-details/carlton-178-172662", "https://www.burbank.com.au/victoria/home-details/carlton-178-178079" ]

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12"]/div[@class="housename"]/span/text()').extract()[0]
        print response.url
        print title
```

and getting the wrong data for some requests. Output is- 
[image]

Please suggest how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't want their website to be scraped so added a technique for scraper to be confused.

In the settings.py change some fields.

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2
```

Comment: scrapy deals requests concurrently. It means scrapy sends a specified number of requests at one time. If you change it to "1", it sends only one request and send next request after receiving response from first request. If you set it "50", scrapy sends 50 requests at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the website stores viewstate.

To get around that you either need to get rid of scrapy's concurrency by setting `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1`.

Otherwise you need to investigate further how the viewstate is generated, it could be IP bound which could mean you need some proxies to get around this.